Identifying a (French?) music video from the 2000s, featuring inanimate objects/plants/animals whose shadows are moving as if they were alive
This was a music video I saw on French TV in the 2000s, probably around 2006 or 2007. I don't remember on which specific TV station.
It just occurred to me that I could take a shot at asking it here, as it featured a fantasy element, namely: objects, plants and animals that are inanimate or dead, yet we see their shadows moving as if they were actually active or alive.
The scene was set indoors. I remember there was a clock whose hands were completely still, but their shadows were moving around as if the clock was actually working. There was also a bunch of dead flowers in a vase, but there was the shadow of apparently fresh flowers on the wall behind. The video also featured an empty bird cage (or possibly a cage with a dead bird inside), yet we see the shadow of a lively bird moving on the wall.
Unfortunately I don't remember the song lyrics at all. They were likely in French, but possibly in English, as back then those were the two most common languages in music videos on French TV.
It was a soft song that probably featured an acoustic guitar and a piano, and possibly other acoustic instruments. I think the singer was a woman.
Does anyone have an idea of what this music video could be?
That was almost 20 years ago, so it's possible that I misremember some elements. Happy to give more details if I can, but I think I already mentioned everything I remember about it.
